# Rendering multiple methods to multiple data table projected in single html under single flask routing

Tags: python-3.x, flask

For the url (datatab), how may I render all different queries for different methods to multiple DataTables in single HTML page?

Currently only the first method is rendering data from db to table1 and other methods aren't working.

[image: screenshot]

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True


def connectToDB():
    import psycopg2
    connectionString = psycopg2.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='null',
                                        password='null', dbname='postgres')
    try:
        return connectionString
    except:
        print("data khuje pachchi na ")


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/datatab)
def doQuery():
    conn = connectToDB()
    cur1 = conn.cursor()
    cur1.execute(
        'select datid,datname,pid,usesysid,usename from pg_stat_activity;')
    results1 = cur1.fetchall()

    return render_template('datatable.html', doQuery=results1)


@app.route('/datatab')
def doQuery1():
    conn = connectToDB()
    cur2 = conn.cursor()
    cur2.execute(
        'select datid,datname,pid,usesysid,usename from pg_stat_activity;')
    results2 = cur2.fetchall()
    return render_template('datatable.html', doQuery1=results2)


def doQuery2():
    conn = connectToDB()
    cur3 = conn.cursor()
    cur3.execute(
        'select relid,indexrelid,schemaname,relname,indexrelname from pg_statio_all_indexes;')
    results3 = cur3.fetchall()

    return render_template('datatable.html', doQuery2=results3)


def doQuery3():
    conn = connectToDB()
    cur4 = conn.cursor()
    cur4.execute(
        'select datid,datname,numbackends,xact_commit,xact_rollback from pg_stat_database;')
    results4 = cur4.fetchall()

    return render_template('datatable.html', doQuery3=results4)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: There is a closing quote missing from `@app.route('/datatab)`

Comment: may be you want to do like [this](https://pastebin.com/Ltjif9qV) ?

Comment: @Pradeepb thanks a lot :) really appreciate your effort regarding solving this .

Comment: I have added it as an answer. Accept it if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.

```
@app.route('/datatab')
def doQuery():
    conn = connectToDB()
    cur1 = conn.cursor()
    cur1.execute('select datid,datname,pid,usesysid,usename from pg_stat_activity;')
    results1 = cur1.fetchall()
    cur2 = conn.cursor()
    cur2.execute('select datid,datname,pid,usesysid,usename from pg_stat_activity;')
    results2 = cur2.fetchall()
    cur3 = conn.cursor()
    cur3.execute('select relid,indexrelid,schemaname,relname,indexrelname from pg_statio_all_indexes;')
    results3 =cur3.fetchall()
    cur4 = conn.cursor()
    cur4.execute('select datid,datname,numbackends,xact_commit,xact_rollback from pg_stat_database;')
    results4 = cur4.fetchall()

    return render_template('datatable.html', doQuery=results1, doQuery1=results2, doQuery2=results3, doQuery3=results4)
```